# WPF and ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection<IRuleCondition>` that I want to display - the `IRuleCondition` interface is used by 2 different classes I want to display, a `RuleCondition` that simply displays one rule condition (info such as priority, property to check and so on), and a `RuleConditionGroup`, that can contain 2 or more `RuleConditions`, grouped in such a way that any of the conditions could match, or all etc.

In the XAML I was wondering is there a way to display a different `ListView.ItemTemplate` depending on what the type is that it encounters in the `ObservableCollection<IRuleCondition>`? Or would I need to implement two different `ObservableCollection`s?

Comment: DataTemplate might solve your problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how this works

This is how the objects are defined

```
public interface Person
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Manager : Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ManagerName { get;set;}
}
```

This is the MainWindow code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<Person> mPeople = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        public ObservableCollection<Person> People
        {
            get
            {
                return mPeople;
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = this;
            mPeople.Add( new Employee{ Name = "x" , ManagerName = "foo"});
            mPeople.Add( new Manager { Name = "y"});

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

This is the MainWindow XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type my:Employee}">
            <StackPanel Background="Green" Width="300">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ManagerName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type my:Manager}">
            <StackPanel Background="Red"
                        Width="300">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}"></ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you can see there are two datatemplates one for Manager and one for Employee

[image]

And this is how the crappy output looks like. Notice the green and red background and extra field displayed for the Employee compared to the manager

Comment: Tried to do it this way, yet everytime I try and start it it says

'Failed to create a 'Type' from the text 'local:EditableRuleConditionModel'.' Line number '13' and line position '53'.

Yet the intellisense is picking up my class names etc fine :S

Comment: Try turning all exceptions on and watch the output window for binding failures

Comment: Trying that now - for some reason when I coped all the DataTemplate stuff from the resource file and into the main .xaml file it worked no problem!

Comment: Finally got it... turns out the ResourceDictionary file needs to be set as a "Page" rather than "Resource" and suddenly it all works now, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Just define two different DataTemplates in the Resources section, one for each RuleCondition type.

Comment: I have something like that already in a Resources file, but I'm not sure how to go about switching them - I've been using this example, but for some reason I keep getting a "Cannot create unknown type" from my DataTemplateSelector class

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx

Sorry, forgot the link to the sample I've been using!

Answer (score 1):

1) Create your two different data templates, just as you say you've already done.
2) Create a custom [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) to choose the appropriate template.

One of your comments states that you're getting an error from your DataTemplateSelector. Verify that you're implementing the class correctly, perhaps paste your implementation. It should be fairly small and straightforward.

Comment: Yeah figured out what was wrong, ResourceFile needed to be set as a "Page" for it to work, thanks for the help :)