# Bind TextBlock to an ObservableCollection<Log> with different template for each Type of Log, where Log.Type is enum

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, enums

I want to bind a `TextBlock` to an `ObservableCollection<Log>`. Each `Log` has different `Type` (enum), each `Type` should be resulting in different `Run`'s `Foreground` (e.g. `Error` is `Red`, `Success` is `Green`).

I've done a quick read to these Q&A:

- [WPF and ObservableCollection<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696467/wpf-and-observablecollectiont)
- [In WPF how to define a Data template in case of enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441901/in-wpf-how-to-define-a-data-template-in-case-of-enum)
- [WPF DataTemplate Binding depending on the type of a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010511/wpf-datatemplate-binding-depending-on-the-type-of-a-property)

But my mind got stuck, because, I'm very new to WPF.

This is the class `Log` and enum `Type`:

```cs
public enum Type
{
    Start = 1,
    Stop = 0,
    Info = 2,
    Success = 4,
    Error = 8
};

public class Log
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

...and this is how I created the collection:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<Log> mLogCollection = new ObservableCollection<Log>();

    public ObservableCollection<Log> LogCollection
    {
        get { return mLogCollection; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;

        mLogCollection.Add(new Log { Type = Log.Type.Error, Message = "Operation failed" });
        mLogCollection.Add(new Log { Type = Log.Type.Success, Message = "Operation complete" });
    }
```

How do I make everything like I want so it will be resulting in something like this?:

```xml
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Operation failed" Foreground="Red"/>
    <Run Text="Operation complete" Foreground="Green"/>
</TextBlock>
```

A balanced XAML and code behind solution is preferred rather than just full XAML.

I'm sorry if my explanation is not clear enough, I'm a bit sleepy right now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to bind Foreground to Type and use value converter which will convert your enum type to required color (Brush).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the easiest way:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <ItemsControl 
        ItemsSource="{Binding LogCollection}"
        >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="local:Log">
                <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding Message}"
                    x:Name="MessageText"
                    />
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="Error">
                        <Setter TargetName="MessageText" Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="Success">
                        <Setter TargetName="MessageText" Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <!-- 
                    Etc. for the other log type values.
                    -->
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

But that's pure XAML and you want code behind. @Evk suggested a value converter for the foreground type, and that's a reasonable way to do it.

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl 
    ItemsSource="{Binding LogCollection}"
    >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="local:Log">
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <local:LogTypeBrushConverter
                    x:Key="LogTypeBrush"
                    />
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Message}"
                Foreground="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource LogTypeBrush}}"
                />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

C#. You defined your enum as `Log.Type` which won't compile, because the `Log` class has a property named `Type`. So I renamed the enum to `LogType`.

```
public class LogTypeBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Color color = Colors.Black;

        switch ((LogType)value)
        {
            case LogType.Start:
                color = Colors.DodgerBlue;
                break;
            case LogType.Stop:
                color = Colors.OrangeRed;
                break;
            case LogType.Info:
                color = Colors.Blue;
                break;
            case LogType.Success:
                color = Colors.Green;
                break;
            case LogType.Error:
                color = Colors.Red;
                break;
        }

        return new SolidColorBrush(color);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Incidentally, `DataContext = this` is a bad idea in general. On a Window it's relatively harmless, but try it on a `UserControl` and you start needing bizarre wokarounds. You can leave that out and bind to `LogCollection` like so:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding LogCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
```